# Page is blank when using serial number with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I made a page and set pagination code in it. The page was working fine.
After inserting code for serial number, all is working fine on first page only and nothing is showing on second page. I have searched a lot for this and tried many options. Now stuk and putting my code below in order to get the adivse of senior and experienced professionals.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $customPagHTML  = "";
    $inputstate     = $wpdb->escape($_POST['inputstate']);;
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM wp_voters WHERE state = '".$inputstate."'";
    $total_query    = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
    $total          = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
    $items_per_page = 20;
    $page           = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
    $offset         = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
    $result         = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY voterID LIMIT ${offset}, 
    ${items_per_page}" );
    $totalPage = ceil($total / $items_per_page);

    if (strcmp($inputstate, 'GA') == 0) { echo "Georgia" ; }
    if (strcmp($inputstate, 'XX') == 0) { echo "Not defined" ; }        
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="add_voter" >
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Please Select State</th>
            <th>
                <select name="inputstate" id="inputstate">
                    <option value="ZZ" selected>List of States</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="XX">Not defined</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th><input type="submit" name="Submitbtn" value="Get the Data"/></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
         <th>Serial Number</th>
         <th>Voter ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Registered On</th>
    </tr>
    <?php global $wpdb;


    \\\\\\\\\\ ADDED NEW CODE WHERE PROBLEM CAN BE 

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if ($page == 1) {
        $count = 0;
    } 
    else {
        $count = ($page + 1) * $limit + 1;
    }
    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\



    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY voterID LIMIT ${offset}, 
    ${items_per_page}" );       
    foreach ( $result as $print ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ++$count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->voterID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->fname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->lname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->phone?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->registered?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<br>
<?php
if ($totalPage > 1) {
    $customPagHTML = '<div align="center" style="font-size:27px;" ><span>Page '.$page.' of 
    '.$totalPage.'</span>'.' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => $totalPage,
    'current' => $page
    )).'</div>';
}
echo $customPagHTML;
?>
```

Comment: Please mark the lines that you added, it makes it easier to locate where the problem can be. Also, what does "nothing is showing on second page" mean exactly? Blank page? No or wrong "serial" number? One thing to spot: is `$_GET['page']` actually set/has the value you expect? You used `cpage` before.

Comment: **WARNING**: You should be using [prepared statements with placeholder values](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) when composing queries. Manual escaping is error-prone and the consequences can be severe.

Comment: Now added comments to highlight the area where problem can be possible.

Comment: I don´t see an assignment for `$limit` anywhere

Comment: The very next line below the commented area i highlighted contains the $LIMIT

Comment: nothing is showing means Blank page

Comment: He meant: `$limit` is never defined before you use it.